# qDeleteAll on nested containers

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt if I have nested QMaps similiar to the following:

```
QMap<int, QMap<int, QMap<int, int*>* >* >
```

Will one call to qDeleteAll take care of recursively cleaning up the memory or do I have to make multiple calls to qDeleteAll manually by iterating over each container?

Comment: The question is why to use pointers to maps. That's almost always unnecessary. And is there a reason to use int* instead of int?

Comment: the int* is actually an array, I am parsing a file and creating the array dynamically on the fly because I don't know how many there will be, ditto with the maps. Everything is being created dynamically. The entire structure is basically an N-dimension look-up table

Comment: That's what std::vector, QVector, QMultiMap etc. are for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ordinary pointers, you need to take care of recursively cleaning up the memory yourself.

If you want the memory to be cleaned automatically, use smart pointers instead. Qt has a wide variety of those available: [Qt Smart Pointers](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Smart_Pointers)

I believe that [QScopedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscopedpointer.html) and [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html) are the ones that may interest you the most.